# Can you use fairlearn for non-parity constraints? (binned monotonicity)

Tags: fairlearn

I'd like to use fairlearn to encode a binned monotonicity constraint on a binned continuous feature, e.g. income. That is, for input x, model h, and income groups {G_1...G_k}, I'd like to enforce:

E[h(x) | x \in G_i] <=  E[h(x) | x \in G_i+1] for i from 0 to k-1.

This constraint fits into the form required in the Fair Reductions paper, where we have our vector mu, which is

mu_j=E[h(x)|x \in G_j] for all j,

and our matrix M which has M_i,i=1 and M_i,(i+1)=-1, and zeros elsewhere.

I was about to try to make an implementation of the Moment class to make a moment for this binned monotonicity constraint, but the documentation for other parts of the code has me worried that fairlearn is only implemented for parity constraints in particular.

For example, in the documentation the _Lagrangian class fairlearn, in fairlearn/fairlearn/reductions/_exponentiated_gradient/_lagrangian.py, it says:

"constraints : fairlearn.reductions.Moment
Object describing the **parity** constraints. This provides the reweighting
and relabelling."

Does this mean that even if find a way to write a moment class for binned monotonicity, I may still run into problems from the rest of the code being geared towards parity constraints only?

Additionally, is there any hope (or existing implementation?) of getting a general implementation of fairlearn where you input mu and M, as opposed to a pre-determined constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Fairlearn maintainer here. The answer is yes, you can use `fairlearn.reductions.Moment`, or more precisely `fairlearn.reductions.ClassificationMoment`, to implement any constraints of the form described in the paper "[A Reductions Approach to Fair Classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.02453.pdf)". Apologies for the mistake in the documentation. We should replace "parity constraints" by "constraints".

If you want to implement this kind of constraint or something more generic along the lines you describe, please open a GitHub issue, and we can help you along! Currently the internal API around creation of new Moment classes is not very well documented.